# He is kind for now!

Tags: present-tense

"He is kind." This means that he is always kind and it's part of his identity. What should I say when I want to say that he is kind just for now or just today? "He is being kind." "He is getting kind." He is becoming kind." Which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

He is being kind.

Or

He is being nice.

Both of these are fine, when talking about someone who might be a bit inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

"He is acting/behaving in a kind way" suggests that his current behavior is kind, but his usual behavior is either different or not known.

"He is kind" is a statement about character: he is kind by nature.

"He is being kind" is a statement about current behavior with an implication that it's unusual.

"He is getting kind" is an unusual phrasing. Grammatically it's fine, but I can't imagine a native speaker saying it that way.  For some reason, we don't usually use the absolute form "kind" as the end state of "getting" or "becoming".  You will almost always hear only the comparative "becoming/getting kinder".  But we don't need the comparative in other cases:  "He's getting/becoming old/rich/bald/decrepit".

To talk about the state change, e.g. from not-kind to kind, most people would insert a mention of the previous state:  "He used to be nasty, but lately he seems to be becoming kind".

Answer (score 0):

Try this: "For the present moment he is kind enough."

This give the impression that one is kind at the present moment, but that he may or may not always or have been always kind.

Comment: That sentence sounds overly wordy/formal. It communicates the right idea, but I don't think I have ever heard anybody speak like that in normal conversation.